# RapidMiner multiple Join operator

Tags: join, inner-join, rapidminer

I want to Join (Inner Join) three CSV datasets in RapidMiner. Right now I am using two Join operatos ((Dataset1 Join Dataset2) Join Dataset3).

Is there any operator or method to Join multiple operators simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

However, you could "roll your own" by using the `Sub Process` operator and place inside that the required number of `Join` operators. The resulting single operator would look and behave like a single operator.